# Database in wordpress. Not update in bitbucket when I pushed code through sourcetree?

Tags: database, wordpress, bitbucket

I have configured wordpress to Bitbucket when I changes push through source tree, the reflect of azure web app service where my code exists. The problem is that about the database cause Team are working on local and use online database but when push the changes the database is not update? How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hi Harry, did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

Databases are generally not saved in your git repository, neither would this be desirable. If you'd like to easily sync your WordPress database between a local and remote install consider a tool like [wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove) or a plugin like [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But my question is that when team are work on their local system then How can manage db changes done by teams  ?

Comment: can any one help me to get out this problem